# Horizontal scroll - center current element

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I'm creating my own horizontal scroll view for a few elements. The problem I have is that I need to have current element centered horizontally (with scroll snapping) no matter what size the viewport is (elements have constant width 300px) and I can't achieve that. Code below doesn't work on every viewport width - I've tried to tweak percentage values but that's not the solution. I need to have constant width of the element AND the gap between elements  (which I currently have) but current elements should be always on the center of the screen.

Wrapper:

```
.carouselItemsWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-rows: 450px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  grid-template-columns: 10% repeat(var(--slide-count), 300px) 10%; //I tried with :before and :after pseudoelements but it didn't work
  scroll-padding-left: calc(10% + 16px); //I thought that would help but no
}

.carouselItemsWrapper:before,
.carouselItemsWrapper:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}
```

Element wrapper:

```
.carouselElementWrapper {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  border: 1px solid var(--marketplaceColor);
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 32px 16px;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

Some screens below:
1 - how it should look (and looks but only on one width)
[image: How it should look (it looks like that only on certain width]

2 - how it looks with my code
[image: How it looks with my code]

Comment: You can decrease your grid-template-columns size and spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. What I needed to do was to just properly calculate width of the pseudoelements and scroll padding:

```
  grid-template-columns: calc((100% - 332px) / 2) repeat(var(--slide-count), 300px) calc(
      (100% - 332px) / 2
    );
  scroll-padding-left: calc((100% - 300px) / 2);
```

Since I know the size of the element and the row gap I've used, I just need to subtract these values from container width ;)